# Login using guard is redirecting to blank page

Tags: laravel, guard

I am trying to login using guard and it login successfully. After login when I redirect to route, it redirects but when I redirect to middleware route it redirect me to blank page.

Here are my routes:

```
Route::get('couponnew/contact', 'Coupon\PageController@contact_show')->name('contact');
Route::get('couponnew/login', 'Coupon\LoginController@index')->name('coupon.login');
Route::post('couponnew/secure/login', 'Coupon\LoginController@secure_login')->name('admin_secure_login');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){
  Route::get('/couponnew/admin','Coupon\AdminDashboardController@dashboard_show')->name('coupondash');
});
```

Login Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Coupon;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Couponmodel\UserNew;

class LoginController extends Controller
{            
    public function index()
    {
        return view('coupon.auth.login');
    }
    
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('user_news');
    }
    
    public function secure_login(Request $request)
    {   
        $credentials = array('email' => $request->input('_username'), 'password' => $request->input('_password'));
        
        if(!$this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->back();
        }else{
             return redirect()->route('coupondash');
        }
    }
}
```

Admin Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Coupon;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Couponmodel\UserNew;

class AdminDashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function dashboard_show()
    {      
      return view('coupon.admin.dashboard');
    }
}
```

After Login, when I redirect to `return redirect()->route('contact');` it works fine but when I redirect to `return redirect()->route('coupondash');` it redirects to blank page.

I don't understand, where I am missing, please help me out.

Comment: What is the content of `coupon.admin.dashboard` view?

Comment: its just, Coning Soon!

Comment: Try to disable the `auth guard` on `coupondash` route, then navigate to `/couponnew/admin` in the browser, is it blank or showing `Coming Soon`...

Comment: I just removed   `Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function(){` and  then then navigate to /couponnew/admin in the browser, its showing blank page

Comment: So? Then there is a problem in your `coupon.admin.dashboard` view..try to fix it first.

Comment: ok, what I have tried is when I put `Route::get('couponnew/contact', 'Coupon\PageController@contact_show')->name('contact');` inside middleware its redirecting to blank page but when I put it outside of middleware its redirecting to right page

Comment: same happened with `Route::get('/couponnew/admin','Coupon\AdminDashboardController@dashboard_show')->name('coupondash');`

Comment: I think, there is some issue with middleware

Comment: I can't guess what happens, since you just provide a limited information. If you said that after remove the middleware (`auth` middleware) you still got a blank page, AFAIK there is a problem with your view, not your middleware.

Comment: Now, its working. When I remove middleware, page is showing Coming Soon!

Comment: What? You said you've already removed the middleware..if after removing middleware the view is showing, then it may a problem with your middleware..maybe you don't have `login` view?

Comment: I have sort it out, thank you dude